# AWS Athena table from python output with dates - dates get wrongly converted

Tags: pandas, amazon-web-services, parquet, amazon-athena

I have a pandas DataFrame containing a date column ("2022-02-02"). I write this table to parquet using pyarrow.

```
df[col] = df[col].astype(str)
df.to_parquet(loc)
```

Now I register this as a table in Athena

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tablename (
  dt_utc date,
  something string,
  else int
)
STORED AS PARQUET
LOCATION 's3://bucket/loc/'
TBLPROPERTIES (
    'skip.header.line.count'='1'
)
```

But I'm not getting the date column to be accepted.

- np.datetime64[D] + athena date results in "-4513749-10-01"
- python str + athena date results in a "Binary Format" error
- python str + athena string works but is not the goal

Comment: I've used Athena a lot, but not Dataframes. Just wondering if you have tried it _without_ converting the date to a string?

Comment: Not a bad suggestion but afraid they are already strings - just put it there to illustrate it. I realised now I'm using pyarrow to write parquet - going to look into this tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think for it to work you need to save the date column, `dt_utc`, as a [date32](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.date32.html#pyarrow.date32) in parquet.

```
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "dt_utc": ["2021-01-02", "2021-01-03"],
        "something": ["abc", "efg"],
        "else": [1, 2],
        
    }
)
df['dt_utc'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dt_utc'])

schema = pa.schema([
    pa.field("dt_utc", pa.date32()),
    pa.field("something", pa.string()),
    pa.field("else", pa.int32()),
    
])

df.to_parquet(loc, schema=schema)
```

EDIT: if you need to change columns to date programatically:

```
date_columns = ["dt_utc"]

for date_column in date_columns:
    df[date_column] = pd.to_datetime(df[date_column])

schema = pa.Schema.from_pandas(df)

schema = pa.schema([
    pa.field(field.name, pa.date32()) if field.name in date_columns else field
    for field in schema
])

df.to_parquet("hello.parquet", schema=schema)
```

Comment: Is there also a way to change one schema and obtain the rest via `pa.Schema.from_pandas`? It's quite some columns I need to specify otherwise :)

Comment: I works perfect, thanks for your second snippet :) Is a timestamp column then a pa.date64?

Comment: No typically for timestamps coming from pandas you'd use `pa.timestamp("ns")` . date64 and date32 are only calendar date (no time of day).